# Converting hh:mm:ss to text using VBA for Excel

Tags: vba, excel, datetime, text

I have a column formatted in `hh:mm:ss` within the cells there is also a `yyyy-mm-dd` added.
They look something like this:

```
1970-01-01 00:01:25
```

I want it to look like this formatted in text:

```
00:01:25
```

If I go about using text to columns manually to remove the yyyy-mm-dd and only importing the `00:01:25` part as text, it works fine.

But if I create a macro doing the same I end up with:

```
:01:25 AM
```

My macro looks like this:

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 9), Array(12, 2)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Thank you all, I have now got it to work by useing the following code(I got help from another board:

```
Sub m()
With Range("D2:D" & Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .NumberFormat = "@"
    .Cells = Evaluate("=INDEX(TEXT(" & .Address & ",""HH:MM:SS""),0)")
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just change the cell's number format to `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: From OP reply to my answer, she needs to do this via VBA. My question to OP is can we just use VBA to change the formatting of the column to suit you?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using excel formula `Text(text;format)` see picture and formula bar.

[image]

Or you can just apply custom text formatting to the **original** column.

[image]

Or do you **need** to do this in VBA?

### Edit. Solution using VBA

`Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss"`

Comment: Thanks but, I need this in VBA, since this is a part of a bigger macro I'm running.

Comment: @AnnaBedzinska I added an Edit to my answer. Will the **Solution using VBA** be OK?

Comment: Thank you, I now have the solution, see my original post.

Comment: You're welcome. Ah, after seeing your update, now I understand, I misunderstood the question.